# capture value from drools excel in java

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I have a java pojo class TestRule having variable ExpectedResultCode with appropriate getter and setter. I am using decision table drools

Now I want to access this set value of ExpectedResultCode in java.

Action: call setResultCode setter of the TestRule class and set the appropriate parameter from excel

TestRule.java-

```
public class TestRule {

    public String ExpectedResultCode;

    public String getResultCode() {
        return ExpectedResultCode;
    }

    public void setResultCode(String ExpectedResultCode) {
        this.ExpectedResultCode = ExpectedResultCode;
    }
}
```

Drools Code:

```
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices
                        .newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository()
                                .getDefaultReleaseId());

                kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
                TestRule testrule = new TestRule();
                kieSession.insert(testrule);
                System.out.println("Output of Result Code:" + testrule.getResultCode());  --> I'm getting Null Value here.
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

In decision table, I changed action to **testrule.setResultCode($param)**

I want to get "Result1" as output, but I'm getting Null value.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You display the object *before* firing the rules:

```
kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
// create a TestRule object: ExpectedResultCode is null
TestRule testrule = new TestRule();
// insert the TestRule object: ExpectedResultCode is still null
kieSession.insert(testrule);
// display TestRule's ExpectedResultCode, which is still null
System.out.println("Output of Result Code:" + testrule.getResultCode());
// fire the rules
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Print the value *after* firing the rules:

```
// now the object TestRule's ExpectedResultCode should have changed.
System.out.println("Output of Result Code:" + testrule.getResultCode());
```